# Accepted electrical raceway material to residential detached garage

Tags: electrical

When exiting a home with an electrical raceway to serve a detached garage, is PVC a generally accepted (code-worthy) raceway material to use? My feeders are carrying one 20A dedicated circuit. My plan is to use a 1" PVC LB condulet and schedule 40 pipe run underground and up into the garage.

Comment: I like Tester101's answer.  But the question and answer leave me asking questions.  How far away? The answer to that might get you the advice to upsize the wire for voltage drop.  Personally I'd  modify this plan just a bit and pull bigger wire plus one more conductor and set a sub-panel in the garage.  If you didn't want to do all of that now, you could set it up now for future expansion with larger wire and one more conductor.   Also when building be sure and use sweep 90's or I prefer using 2-45's and straight pipe between to get depth at each end, I think that makes pulling easier.

Answer (score 2):

No problem. [Schedule 40 PVC conduit is suitable for direct burial](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/38877/33), so there's no problem with that. As long as you're using schedule 40 PVC **conduit**, and not schedule 40 PVC **DWV pipe**.

It may or may not be required by code, but it's good practice to install expansion fittings wherever the conduit enters/exits the ground. This allows the ground and conduit to move, while preventing damage to the conduit during said movement.